# Switching between templates displayed in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I'm beginning to work on a Django application. I'd like to have two different views which switch dynamically when the user clicks on one of the tabs on the screen. Here is essentially what I have:

base.html:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/base.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'teams')">Teams</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'scenarios')">Scenarios</button>
    </div>

    <div class="content container">
        <div class="tab-options">
            <div class="teams-tab" id="teams-tab">
                {% block teams %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="scenarios-tab" id="scenarios-tab">
                {% block scenarios %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

teams.html:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}

{% block teams %}
<body>
  <form action="{% url 'webapp:results' %}" method="get">
      <h1>You are on the teams page!</h1>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Results!"><br>
  </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}

{% block scenarios %}
<body>
  <form action="{% url 'webapp:results' %}" method="get">
      <h1>You are on the scenarios page!</h1>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Results!"><br>
  </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

base.js:

```
function changeTab(event, tab) {
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-options");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    if (tab == "teams") {
        document.getElementById("teams-tab").style.display = "block"
    } else if (tab == "scenarios") {
        document.getElementById("scenarios-tab").style.display = "block"
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working. When the page initially loads, I see the "scenarios" block fill as expected, but as soon as I click on a tab the blocks disappear and I'm only left with what is in base.html. Is there a better way to switch between these tabs? What's wrong with the way I'm trying to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

When you load index page, Django tries to render index.html template. This template extends base.html and overrides only `scenarios` block and in the end html will look like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/base.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'teams')">Teams</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'scenarios')">Scenarios</button>
    </div>

    <div class="content container">
        <div class="tab-options">

            <div class="teams-tab" id="teams-tab">
            </div>

            <div class="scenarios-tab" id="scenarios-tab">
                <body>
                    <form action="{% url 'webapp:results' %}" method="get">
                        <h1>You are on the scenarios page!</h1>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Results!"><br>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When you set `display: block`, content doesn't appear, because there is no html to display.

In order to fix it, you need to render all tabs and then manipulate them using js.